# Trigger to update a date field on one table when another table is updated

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, trigger

I want to be able to update a date filed in one table when another table is updated.
I have the following two tables: `Transdetails`, `Customers`.

In the `Customers` table I have a field called `ZLastDateOfSale`. I want this field updated with the current date when `Transdetails.TradingDate` is updated per Customer.

Can you please help me create this Trigger?

My Example is below:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trg_LastSaleDate ON dbo.Transheaders
    AFTER UPDATE
AS
    IF UPDATE(TradingDate)
    BEGIN
        update dbo.Customers
            set dbo.Customers.ZLastSale = dbo.Transheaders.TradingDate
        from dbo.Customers
    END
```

**Updated Example 11/05/2014:**

```
CREATE TRIGGER trg_LastSaleDate ON dbo.Transheaders
    AFTER UPDATE
AS
    IF UPDATE(TradingDate)
    BEGIN
        UPDATE c
            SET ZLastSales = i.TradingDate
        FROM dbo.Customers AS c
          JOIN inserted AS i
            ON i.UniqueID = c.UniqueID     -- use the appropriate column for joining
          JOIN deleted AS d
            ON  i.AccountID = d.AccountID
            AND ( i.TradingDate <> d.TradingDate
               OR d.TradingDate IS NULL
                ) ;
    END ;
```

Hello,

Thank you so much for your input and response. 
I changed your provided example, ran the script and it was successful, however, what it did was to update the ZLastSale date on all Customers with todays date. This field should be blank and only update moving forward from now when the Trigger fires. This field should only be updated upon a sale from a Customer.

Also, when I tested entering a new transaction with a date of 30/05/2014 it didn’t update the required ZLastSale field. It is displayed as 11/05/2014 so something is not working right somewhere.

My ID’s for each table are:

```
Customers.UniqueID and Transheaders.AccountID
```

Thanks again for your help.

Comment: What did you try yourself?

Comment: Start by looking for documentation about CREATE TRIGGER - if you then have a particular problem update your question with the details.  Thanks!

Comment: Hello, this is my example. It runs and up dates the custom field, however when a new transaction is entered into the database the custom field is not updated which is what I want.

Comment: Please **do not** put code samples or sample data into comments - since you cannot format it, it's **extremely hard** to read it.... Instead: **update** your question by editing it to provide that additional information! Thank you.

Comment: Good morning, I have updated as requested.

Comment: Good Morning, please see my reply above .. Thank You.

Comment: Can you add the `CREATE TABLE` definitions for the 2 tables in the question?

Comment: Not sure how .. sorry

Comment: Actually, ignore the update of all records on Customer comment. This was because the field was set to a date time field. I’ve changed it to be text and it now doesn’t do that.

Answer (score 3):

You should be using the `inserted` and `deleted` pseudo tables to find out the  rows for which the column was affected by the trigger - and then update only the related rows in the second table:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trg_LastSaleDate ON dbo.Transheaders
    AFTER UPDATE
AS
    IF UPDATE(TradingDate)
    BEGIN
        UPDATE c
            SET ZLastSale = i.TradingDate
        FROM dbo.Customers AS c
          JOIN inserted AS i
            ON i.CustomerID = c.CustomerID     -- use the appropriate column for joining
          JOIN deleted AS d
            ON  i.TransheadersID = d.TransheadersID
            AND ( i.TradingDate <> d.TradingDate
               OR d.TradingDate IS NULL
                ) ;
    END ;
```